# Regex: Capturing optional beginning or ending groups/subgroups

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to find different emoticons in a string. Some of the emoticons have hats [example party hat emoticon:  *<:-) ] 
so I'm trying to add an optional group for hats at the beginning of the expression. The problem I'm having is that when I add an optional group to the beginning or end of the expression, it starts to match empty strings. I read some of the other questions on here regarding this topic, but I'm still having trouble understanding why this is happening and what I can do to fix it. Here's what I have so far:

```
 r"""
 (                 
     ([{}]|K|(E-)|(\*<))?   # Optional Hat/Toupee
     [:;8B=xX#%*0]          # Eyes
     [-o]?                  # Optional Nose
     [DbP)(>{c$I3/\J&]      # Mouth/Tongue
 )"""
```

If I try to match :-) in a string, the regular expression parser returns:

```
[(':-)', '', '', '')]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have redundant capturing groups. Remove them/make them non-capturing `(?:[{}]|K|E-|\*<)?`

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. The matching of empty strings doesn't change when I add the non-capturing group.

Comment: If you copy and replace the snippet with mine, I'm quite sure there won't be any empty string. If it still does, please show your code.

Comment: @nhahtdh You were right. I was confused about how capturing vs. non-capturing groups work, but I think I've figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each parenthesis pair adds a capturing group to your expression. To debug your regex, name your capturing groups with `?P<name>`:

```
regexp = re.compile("(?P<A>(?P<B>[{}]|K|(?P<C>E-)|(?P<D>\*<))?[:;8B=xX#%*0][-o]?[DbP)(>{c$I3/\J&])")
```

Then you have:

```
>>> print regexp.match(':-)').groupdict()
{'A': ':-)', 'C': None, 'B': None, 'D': None}
```

which makes sense to me.

Note that unless you want to capture those specific parts of the emoticons, the C and D groups look unnecessary to me. And unless you want to capture the hat part separately, the B group can be made non-capturing by using `(?:)` instead of `()`.

Comment: This was really helpful for me. I made all of the hat groups non-capturing, and this seems to have solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

message1 = "I'm happy today :-)"
message2 = 'Me too *<:-) :3'
message3 = 'I prefer emoticons like this: =D =) =P'

regexp = re.compile("(([{}*<]+)?[:;8B=xX#%*0][-o]?[DbP)(>{c$I3/\J&])")
emoticons1 = regexp.findall(message1)
emoticons2 = regexp.findall(message2)
emoticons3 = regexp.findall(message3)
print(emoticons1)
print(emoticons2)
print(emoticons3)
```

If you want have only two capture per emoticons, one for emoticon and another for hat, you need have only two group.

And, where: `[DbP)(>{c$I3/\J&]`
You can not use `\` at `\J` in charclass. In charclass, everthing is character. If you want get `J`, you should only use `J`.